# Batch file to call multiple batch files and keep going after errors

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt, command, command-line-interface

I have a batch file like this, the issue that I have is that if the first batch file fails, the second one never gets started, how can I get them to both keep going?

```
@echo off
MapNetworkDrive_J.cmd
MapNetworkDrive_Y.cmd
```

I have tried this:

```
@echo off
start MapNetworkDrive_J.cmd
start MapNetworkDrive_Y.cmd
```

however, this starts two new command windows which after they are done remain open in the users session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the call command:

```
@echo off
call MapNetworkDrive_J.cmd
call MapNetworkDrive_Y.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `start` by `cmd -c`